# JavaScript Bookmarklet: Use ID, redirect to CMS URL

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet, bookmarks

my plan is to create a bookmarklet that redirects a page to the connected CMS page. The page URL looks like that:

```
https://www.website.com/film/harry-potter_885104.html
```

The connected CMS page looks like this:

```
https://cms2.website.com/admin/internet/de/movie/885104/edit
```

To make it more challenging there is another combination: /series/... and the concurring path /internet/de/tvseries/... in the CMS. Is there a way to detect with of them applies and than redirect to one or the other? The alternative would be to use two bookmarklets which is also fine.

Is there any way to fetch the ID (885104) from the URL and redirect the page to the CMS URL using a bookmarklet?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

See a [live example here](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQChEoAIF4D5IN4B0B2l2QPSYMYHsUBnAF0gFcAnAGxkiWAAtjiAHQgLmwHceA6LgKYAjQgEtiA3vgC2mAGaiqshgEMKFAJ4BaFnmYCKAfQAcxgKwBGAAwAWXk2lV6qDJHxFSlGtEhdRKABM8Ll4qPBwVYlECewoBORcMdxJIUQDaL15CFipxEAByQ3zwAG0LAF0snLz83mKSq3LE9GxIPBYBNH9IQhVpAUgWFQBzAWasTF9-IJCwiKiYhji5WgADJlYObBxpQgAmfmExCSk8WRUA6X9MfwkKFAFiTACBTGk8ADdRV4ASBDSAL6YAQBcSrcatdqdVJoB5cSDEFRCcZ+QLBXhQlAgdbMNicXC7A6CETiSQyTAXK4oG4oO4PJ4vN6fb6YP6A4Gg4irAA0kEKQioKhQAGtiqgAeAIABuYBAA)

```
const url = window.location.href
const id = url.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
window.open(`https://cms2.website.com/admin/internet/de/movie/${id}/edit`, '_blank')
```